# How can I homebrew a unique demonic animal companion for my player's moon druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, druid, animal-companions, creature-size

As a DM I get a question from one of my players in my group, there are five people. However, it is the third level tiefling moon druid who asked "if he can have an animal companion later on in the campaign." There are no Rangers in the party, and he does not want to Multiclass.

Moreover, I said "I will work on something for him," and " do you have some idea for a type of creature it can be." the answer he gives is " it should be one-of-a-kind demonic animal, maybe created by fusing multiple creatures and inorganic materials in a ritual."

Since this is the first campaign that I'm running, in the fifth edition of D&D.  I want like some help to developing ideas of such a creature and lore for the creature, and as well going to use third-party Materials. My current idea is a defender archetype with a fiendish background creature.

The third-party materials:

- Baby Bestiary 5e Beast Companion
- Baby Bestiary Handbook Vol.1
- Baby Bestiary Handbook Vol.2

Comment: Hi C.G. and welcome to RPG.stackexchange. Kindly take the [tour]. Unfortunately, we're not really the place to go for idea generation --- we have a laser-like focus on Q&A only, only questions that have a correct answer and then those correct answers. Idea generation is off-topic here, but you can find good guidance in the various [RPG forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) around the internet. If you stick around to earn 20 reputation, you can also write in [chat]. Welcome!

Comment: However, we potentially *COULD* answer something like "Is this provided method of providing an animal companion to a Druid balanced?" alongside your first draft. Again, Welcome to rpg.stackexchange

Comment: We have an excellent Meta question on [How to Ask Homebrew Balance Questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8171/how-should-i-ask-about-my-dd-5e-homebrew-being-balanced).I strongly recommend that you read this and try to follow through with the content inside. I think it'll help you put together better homebrew, better homebrew questions, and give you results that you can use at your table. It'll also vastly increase the odds of a successful Q&A for you here.

Comment: I don't think a *demonic fusion of multiple creatures and inorganic materials* is an appropriate companion for a druid. (Also, I don't think it qualifies as an "animal".) I suggest both of you re-read the druid class description.

Comment: Thank for the comments i will work on something else for "him" instead